# Fill column C based on values in columns A & B using pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to create a new column in a pandas dataframe with its values based on values from two other columns.

I tried using nested if statements to check the values in each column, but it ended up only checking the first row and filling the rest of the rows based on the first entry.

```
if np.where(df['Person A']=='Yes'):
    if np.where(df['Person B']=='Yes'):
        df['Consensus'] = 'Person A said yes, then Person B said yes'
    elif np.where(df['Person B']=='No'):
        df['Consensus'] = 'Person B said yes, then person B said no'
```

Let me know if I can clarify anything - I'm a first timer!

Comment: Add some example data, and what your expected output looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one of the way on the same lines

```
def f(x,y):
    if x =='Yes':
            if y =='Yes':
            return 'Person A said yes, then Person B said yes'
        elif y =='No':
            return = 'Person B said yes, then person B said no'

df['Consensus'] = df.apply(lambda row: f(row['Person A'], row['Person B']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a proposed solution: Create a function for your logic and apply it on the dataframe.

Execution:

1. Build your dataframe & constants:

   ```
   df = pd.DataFrame({"Person A":["Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","No","No"],
                  "Person B":["Yes","Yes","No","No","No","No"]})

   yes = 'Person A said yes, then Person B said yes'
   no = 'Person A said yes, then person B said no'
   ```

result

```
    Person A    Person B
    0   Yes         Yes
    1   Yes         Yes
    2   Yes         No
    3   Yes         No
    4   No          No
    5   No          No
```

2. create your function

   ```
   def yourfunc(row):
       if row['Person A']=="Yes" and row['Person B']=="Yes":
           return yes
       if row['Person A']=="No" and row['Person B']=="No":
           return no
       return "TBA"
   ```
3. Apply your function:

   ```
   df['Consensus'] = df.apply(yourfunc, axis=1)
   ```

end result:

```
    Person A    Person B    Consensus
0   Yes         Yes         Person A said yes, then Person B said yes
1   Yes         Yes         Person A said yes, then Person B said yes
2   Yes         No          TBA
3   Yes         No          TBA
4   No          No          Person A said yes, then person B said no
5   No          No          Person A said yes, then person B said no
```